# Cannnot find "Array Out of Bounds Exception" Java

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I am creating a search engine that reads in a text file, and prints out a word that a user can search for. I'm currently creating an index of arrays to be searched for. More information can be found here: http://cis-linux1.temple.edu/~yates/cis1068/sp12/homeworks/concordance/concordance.html

When I run this program right now, I get an "Array Index Out of Bounds Exception"

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 43
    at SearchEngine.main(SearchEngine.java:128)

Can anyone help debug?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class SearchEngine {


public static int getNumberOfWords (File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int numWords = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
    numWords++;
    scan.next();
    }
    scan.close();

    return numWords;
}

public static void readInWords (File input, String [] x) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
    int i = 0;
    while (scan.hasNext() && i<x.length) {
        x[i] = scan.next();
        i++;
        }
    scan.close();
}

public static int getNumOfDistinctWords (File input, String [] x) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
    int count = 0;
    int i = 1;
    while (scan.hasNext() && i<x.length) {
    if (!x[i].equals(x[i-1])) {
    count++;
    }
    i++;
    }
    scan.close();
    return count;
}

public static void readInDistinctWords (String [] x, String [] y) {
    int i = 1;
    int k = 0;
    while (i<x.length) {
        if (!x[i].equals(x[i-1])) {
        y[k] = x[i];
        k++;
        }
    i++;
    }
}

public static int getNumberOfLines (File input) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int numLines = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        numLines++;
        scan.nextLine();
        }
    scan.close();
    return numLines;
}

public static void readInLines (File input, String [] x) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
    int i = 0;
    while (scan.hasNextLine() && i<x.length) {
        x[i] = scan.nextLine();
        i++;
        }
    scan.close();
}
```

Main

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

 try {

    //gets file name
System.out.println("Enter the name of the text file you wish to search");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = kb.nextLine();
    String TXT = ".txt";
    if (!fileName.endsWith(TXT)) {
        fileName = fileName.concat(TXT);
    }

    File input = new File(fileName);

//First part of creating index
System.out.println("Creating vocabArray");
int NUM_WORDS = getNumberOfWords(input);
//System.out.println(NUM_WORDS);
String [] wordArray = new String[NUM_WORDS];
readInWords(input, wordArray);
Arrays.sort(wordArray);
int NUM_DISTINCT_WORDS = getNumOfDistinctWords(input, wordArray);
String [] vocabArray = new String[NUM_DISTINCT_WORDS];
readInDistinctWords(wordArray, vocabArray);
System.out.println("Finished creating vocabArray");



System.out.println("Creating concordanceArray");
int NUM_LINES = getNumberOfLines(input);
String [] concordanceArray = new String[NUM_LINES];
readInLines(input, concordanceArray);
System.out.println("Finished creating concordanceArray");



System.out.println("Creating invertedIndex");
int [][] invertedIndex = new int[NUM_DISTINCT_WORDS][10];
int [] wordCountArray = new int[NUM_DISTINCT_WORDS];
int lineNum = 0;
    while (lineNum<concordanceArray.length) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(concordanceArray[lineNum]);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            int wordPos = Arrays.binarySearch(vocabArray, scan.next());
            wordCountArray[wordPos]+=1;
            for(int i = 0; i < invertedIndex.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < invertedIndex[i].length; i++) {
            if (invertedIndex[i][j] == 0) {
            invertedIndex[i][j] = lineNum;
            break;
            } } }
            }
        lineNum++;
        }
System.out.println("Finished creating invertedIndex");

}

    catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
    System.out.println("File Not Found");
}




} //main
```

} //class

Comment: where are you getting hte exception?

Comment: Define "can't find"; the exception will show you precisely where the error is occurring.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 43
 at SearchEngine.main(SearchEngine.java:128)

Comment: @user1302023 - Check the index with a value of 43 at line 128.

Comment: see my edit... better to ask a different question rather than ask in the comments by the way.

Answer (score 6):

```
for(int j = 0; j < invertedIndex[i].length; i++) {
```

should probably be

```
j++
```

not

```
i++
```

Update after your fix.

That means that `Arrays.binarySearch(vocabArray, scan.next())` is not finding the item being searched for.  You cannot assume that the vocabArray has the item you are searching for.  You will need to add an `if(... < 0)` for the binarySearch call.

Comment: fixed the it to j++ and now I'm getting this:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at SearchEngine.main(SearchEngine.java:126)

Comment: But if you follow the code, it basically takes every single word from the txt file, and adds it to vocabArray. Then it takes every line from the file, adds it to concordanceArray. The binary search, searches each word in each line of concordanceArray and returns the index in vocabArray where it is found. So in theory, vocabArray should have it.